# Why does foldr return immediately?

Tags: haskell

Newbie to Haskell.

Trying to figure out why:

```
foldr (\_ _ -> 1) 2 [1..]
```

returns `1` immediately, however:

```
foldl (\_ _ -> 1) 2 [1..]
```

runs forever.

Reading some [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#foldr), but stuck at some `#.`s .

Help me out. (Run tests on Windows GHC 7.10.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That source is the default `Foldable` implementation of `foldr`, it's not the actual implementation for lists. The actual [implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#foldr) is straightforward:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr k z = go
          where
            go []     = z
            go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
```

The result of `foldr (\_ _ -> 1) 2 [1..]` can be understood by substitution:

```
foldr (\_ _ -> 1) 2 [1..] 
go [1..]                  
go (1 : [2..])            -- evaluate [1..]
(\_ _ -> 1) 1 (go [2..])  -- evaluate `go` at (:) case
1                         -- evaluate expression
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in GHC, foldl is actually implemented by foldr:

```
foldl :: forall a b. (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
{-# INLINE foldl #-}
foldl k z0 xs =
  foldr (\(v::a) (fn::b->b) -> oneShot (\(z::b) -> fn (k z v))) (id :: b -> b) xs z0
```

So no matter your folding function evaluates the parameters or not, it will build a composed function from the list and pass the initial value to it, so will not terminate with infinite list.